# How to make tree route in expressjs

Tags: express, routes

I have some routes into my blog. Strucrure looks like this:

```
/admin - admin
/login - login page
/videos - videocatalog
/:article - single article w/o category
/:category/:article -single article with category
```

i tryed to use

```
router.get('/!(admin):url', function(req, res) {
```

bot didnt got something like i needed

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest you to use this architecture on your blog, since express won't know the difference between **/:article** and **/:category**.

What I would do is set those inside an **/articles** parent route, like this:

```js
router.get('/admin', function (req, res) { });
router.get('/login', function (req, res) { });
router.get('/videos', function (req, res) { });
router.get('/articles/:article', function (req, res) { });
router.get('/articles/:categoryOrArticle/:article?', function (req, res) { 

  if(req.params.article) {
    // If all parameters are passed to the url the user is accessing a categorized article
    let category = req.params.categoryOrArticle;
    let article = req.params.article;
  } else {
    // Else, user is accessing a non-categorized article
    let article = req.params.categoryOrArticle;
  }

});
```

And to get the article or category just use **req.params.article** or **req.params.category**.